# Unable to install git - Unmet dependencies error (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: git, installation

when i try to install git (`sudo apt-get install git`), I get following error:

```
root@ServerC--Frrole2:/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.25# sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:1.7.5.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:1.7.5.4-.) but it is not going to be installed
 sun-java6-jre : Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-2natty1) but it is not going to be installed or
                          ia32-sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-2natty1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If anyone know how to fix this, please HELP!

EDIT:

---

Now, after running some more commands. I get following state.

```
root@ServerC--Frrole2:/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.25# apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package sun-java6-jre needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I don't know what installing git has to do with installation of Java. I have java installed with tomcat already.

```
root@ServerC--Frrole2:/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.25# which java
/usr/tomcat/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

**Add this:**

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

**Update system:**

`apt-get update`

`apt-get upgrade`

**Install git:**

`apt-get install git`

Comment: I'm looking for this. Thanks, @Daniel Díaz.

Answer (score 0):

did you try running `sudo apt-get -f install` as the output suggests?

also, looking a this, sun-java6 isnt available anymore generally speaking. After running the previous command, try again and it should try for the open jdk instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may try another repository. I ve faced the same problem and i have just switched to the repository "main server". and it is OK

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem, and I resolved it as follows.

1. I upgraded all packages ([see this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886765/cannot-install-git-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts))
2. I went through [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)
3. I ran git installation command (`apt-get install git`)